# How to resolve ValueError: Shapes (None, 7) and (None, 5) are incompatible''?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, speech-recognition

I am trying the 'Speech emotion recognition system' as described in https://github.com/faroukAllam/SER/blob/master/speech-emotion-recognition-conv1d-2%20(3).ipynb

Here are the necessary parts of my code,

```
X = extracted_df.drop(labels="labels", axis=1)
Y = extracted_df["labels"]
testX = extracted_testdf.drop(labels="labels", axis=1)
testY = extracted_testdf["labels"]
lb = LabelEncoder()
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(Y))
Y
lb = LabelEncoder()
testY = np_utils.to_categorical(lb.fit_transform(testY))
testY
X_train = X
y_train = Y
X_test = testX
y_test = testY

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, random_state=42, test_size=0.1, shuffle=True)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, X_val.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape, y_val.shape

# Standardize data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
X_val = scaler.transform(X_val)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, X_val.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape, y_val.shape

# We have to use 1-dimensional CNN which need specifical shape:
X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=2)

X_val = np.expand_dims(X_val, axis=2)
X_test = np.expand_dims(X_test, axis=2)
X_train.shape
earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_acc",
                              mode = 'auto', patience = 5,
                              restore_best_weights = True)

learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc',
                                            patience=3,
                                            verbose=1,
                                            factor=0.5,
                                            min_lr=0.00001)

from keras import backend as K

def recall_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def precision_m(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def f1_m(y_true, y_pred):
    precision = precision_m(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall_m(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(512, kernel_size=5, strides=1,
                        padding="same", activation="relu",
                        input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))


model.add(layers.Conv1D(512, kernel_size=5, strides=1,
                       padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1,
                        padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"))

# model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256)))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

# model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256)))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))

# model.add(Attention(128))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["acc"])

EPOCHS = 50
batch_size = 64

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                    epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=batch_size,
                    callbacks=[earlystopping, learning_rate_reduction])
```

When I execute this, it gives the below error. **ValueError: Shapes (None, 7) and (None, 5) are incompatible** When I searched for the error I understood that this happens as there is a mismatch between the expected output shape of the model and the actual shape of the labels. But I do not have an idea about the way to resolve it as I am new to this area. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?